# Summarizing Text Before After and Within parentheses in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table - some with parentheses () and some without

```
    Companies    
    Arbino (Arb) Corp Ltd
    Arbino (Arb) Corp Ltd; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank
    Zinga
    Zinga; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank
    Bubble Zip (Bzip) Corp
    Bubble Zip (Bzip) Corp; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank
```

I need to create a column like this - i.e. text within the parentheses AND text after the parentheses.

```
Companies                                   Companies_Compressed
Arbino (Arb) Corp                           Arb Corp Ltd
Arbino (Arb) Corp; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank      Arb Corp Ltd; Bak Bank
Zinga                                       Zinga
Zinga; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank                  Zinga; Bak Bank 
Bubble Zip (Bzip) Corp                      Bzip Corp 
Bubble Zip (Bzip) Corp; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank Bzip Corp; Bak Bank
```

I also need to create a separate table to tell everyone that Arbino = Arb

```
Company_prefix    short_form  
Arbino            Arb
Bakroaho          Bak
Bubble Zip        Bzip
```

what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace any `alphanumerics` before special character `(` `or` special characters `()` with `''` using `str.replace`

```
df['Companies_Compressed']=df['Companies'].str.replace('((\w+\s){1,2}(?=[(])|[()])','')
```

For the second question;

```
df1=df.assign(Company_prefix=df['Companies'].str.extract('(\w+\s\w+|\w+)(?=\s[(])'),short_form =df['Companies'].str.extract('(?<=[(])(.*?)(?=[)])')).dropna()
print(df1)
```

Comment: Thank a lot. The first question, the Companies_Compressed is showing like this Arbino Arb Corp. Second question is fine.

Comment: First question it works for me. That is strange! Try use `df['Companies_Compressed']=df['Companies'].str.replace('(\w+\s(?=[(])|[()])','')` instead.

Comment: This works great. Thank you. It doesn't work if there are two words before the (). E.g. Bubble Zip (BZIP) corporation shows as Bubble Zip BZIP Corporation.

Comment: You are right it wont work for ` Bubble Zip (BZIP)`.This had been included in the question though

Comment: Please Try `df['Companies_Compressed']=df['Companies'].str.replace('((\w+\s){1,2}(?=[(])|[()])','')` for the first question

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this regex:

```
pattern = '\((\w+)\) (\w+)'
df['Companies_Compressed'] = (df.Companies.str.extractall(pattern)
                                .agg(' '.join, axis=1)
                                .groupby(level=0).apply('; '.join)
                                .fillna(df['Companies'])
                             )

                                Companies Companies_Compressed
0                       Arbino (Arb) Corp             Arb Corp
1  Arbino (Arb) Corp; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank   Arb Corp; Bak Bank
2                                   Zinga                  NaN
```

Comment: works good. Is there a way to convert for e.g. Zinga; Bakroaho (Bak) Bank to Zinga; Bak Bank. The current code removes zinga. I have edited the question.